# str.replace does not replace the $1

Tags: javascript, regex, str-replace

I'm trying to make a little highlight function.
The Problem i have is, that i does not insert the matched into the $1.
My function looks like

```
getMatch(str, search) {
    let result = str.replace(new RegExp(search, 'gi'), '<span class="match">$1</span>');
    return result;
}
```

as you can see, it should wrap the match. but it does not.
here an example how i use it:

```
let string = 'My string with higlighting.';
let match = getMatch(string, 'With');
```

my expected result is:

`My string <span class="match">with</span> highlighting.`

but i just get:

`My string <span class="match">$1</span> highlighting.`

so the $1 was not replaced by the matching.

How can i solve that?

Comment: I think you want to wrap the whole match with `span`, right? Then replace `$1` with `$&`.

Comment: That i've tried already. the problem is there is that i search case insensitive but the string is lower or uppercase. so i can not replace with the search string, i need replace with the match

Comment: Your `'With'` has no capturing groups, thus, `$1` is parsed as a literal string. `$&` will insert the *whole match value* in the replacement.

Comment: Or if you also want to populate the `match` attribute with the match value, also add `$&` there: `'<span class="$&">$&</span>'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `'With'` has no capturing groups, thus, `$1` is parsed as a literal string.

If you want to wrap the whole match with `span`, replace `$1` with `$&`.

```
getMatch(str, search) {
    let result = str.replace(new RegExp(search, 'gi'), '<span class="match">$&</span>');
    return result;
}
```

See [MDN `replace` reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter):

> `$&`  Inserts the matched substring.

Answer (score 2):

The with is not a capturing group, you should transform it by adding parenthesis :

```
let string = 'My string with higlighting.';
let match = getMatch(string, '(With)');
```

Output will be:

```
My string <span class="match">with</span> higlighting.
```